postgres - How to parse json array elements?
PostgreSQL 15.4
Below is the postgres table table1:
CREATE TABLE table1 (
 id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 name TEXT,
 skills JSON
);

with below rows inserted:
INSERT INTO table1 (id, name, skills) VALUES
 (1, 'Alice', ‘[
                 {“sid" : 11, "description" : “Cardio"}, 
                 {"sid" : 13, "description" : “Anesthist"}
              ]'
 ),
 (2, ‘Bob', ‘[
               {“sid" : 10, "description" : “Gastro"}, 
               {"sid" : 9, "description" : “Oncology"}
              ]’
 ),
 (3, ‘Sam', ‘[
              ]’
 );

Below is the desired output, upon running select query:
id   name     skill
---------------------
1   Alice     [“Cardio”,“Anestisht”]
2   Bob       ["Gastro","Oncology"]
3   Sam       []

where skill column is TEXT type

Tried below  query
select  
id, name, d ->> 'description' as skill 
from table1, 
json_array_elements(skills) as d

that gives duplicate rows(as shown below) with a missing row, which is incorrect
id   name     skill
---------------------
1   Alice     Cardio
1   Alice     Anestisht
2   Bob       Gastro
2   Bob       Oncology


Use array_agg() to aggregate the descriptions into an array:
select
  id,
  name,
  array_agg(skill ->> 'description') as skill
from table1, json_array_elements(skills) AS skill
group by 1, 2

See live demo.

To return rows for people with no skills as well, here's one way:
  id,
  name,
  array_agg(skill ->> 'description')
from table1, json_array_elements(skills) AS skill
group by 1, 2
union all
select
  id,
  name,
  array[]::text[]
from table1
where json_array_length(skills) = 0

See live demo.

I tried running with skills as empty as shown here, it doesn't work. Desired output is 3 rows, but it shows two rows

@overexchange See edited answer for how to include skillless people too.

Third column(skill) in first SELECT query is of type _text
As per demo code here, third column value in SELECT query says NULL, but the desired output is []. Tried '[]'::_text instead of null in second SELECT query, but no luck

@overexchange Changed to returning empty array for no skill. Demo link updated too.

How to order by name for this combination of select query?

@overexchange You'd wrap the whole thing in parentheses to make sure an order by you add at the end applies to the whole thing, as opposed to just the second out of the two unioned selects: demo.

@overexchange yes: select * from ( <query in answer> ) x order by name (the x gives an alias to the inner query which is a syntactical requirement)

So, we see error in client code: pq unable to parse array expected '{' at offset 0. How to get regular SQL arrays with curly brace {} to address this error? Because for skills, we get the output as: [[1 2 3][1 2 3][1 2 3]] with square brancker but not curly brace {

"Regular SQL arrays" use the square bracket, not the curly bracket. Please explain why you believe an array should use curly brackets.

Use jsonb_path_query_array(). It gets you a jsonb array as shown in your expected result, not a regular SQL array of text.
demo at db<>fiddle
select
  id,
  name,
  jsonb_path_query_array(skills::jsonb,'$[*].description') as skill
from table1;




id
name
skill




1
Alice
["Cardio", "Anesthist"]


2
Bob
["Gastro", "Oncology"]


3
Sam
[]



If you're on an older version of PostgreSQL (versions 9.3-11), you can expand and collapse the array in a scalar subquery, then coalesce() the null to an empty array:
select
  id,
  name,
  coalesce((select json_agg(e->>'description')from json_array_elements(skills)e)
           ,'[]') as skill
from table1;


From the testing aspect, I tested with count(*) on table1 vis-a-vis count(*) on select query output. How to test first two column values in table1 vis-a-vis first two column values in select query output?

@overexchange Can you show an example, what that would look like? I'm not sure I follow. It sounds like you're describing a join, but I doubt that's what you mean: select * from table1 as t1 full join (the_select_statement) as t2 using(id,name);

yes, that is what I meant
